# Bootstrap 3 elements are not showing ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

When I add the bootstrap 3 'thumbnail' item to the class for my div it doesn't show. Here is my exact CSS3 markup. Same goes for the jumbotron.

```
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #3f0070;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/photo.png" alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the exact html you are using as well as the css

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap 3 dependency files were bugged. I reinstalled using Nuget package manager. Now, everything is back to default. Thanks.